# How to create email accounts automatically in a Laravel app using CLI - Plesk panel, Cron Job or Laravel Queue

Tags: php, linux, laravel, email

I am creating a website using Laravel-React on a Linux Ubuntu20 server. I have a pro Plesk panel in it.

In my web app when a user register the app, I automatically create a subdomain like "username.domain.com" and the thing I want to do is when a user registered I want to create an email automatically like "username@domain.com".

Is there a way to do that with CLI or Laravel queue or using something else. All email account must have max 100mb quota.

Comment: I guess you should check plesk api  for mail creation REST : https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/api-rpc/about-rest-api/reference/managing-mail/creating-mail-accounts.34499/  - XML : https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/api-rpc/about-xml-api/reference/managing-mail/creating-mail-accounts.34499/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I guess I didn't see this doc, I search a lot but I didn't know it. I will check it thank you